# Javascript validation for duplicate username

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have created 2 pages in asp.net login and signup.

Now I want to check whether the username entered is already present before inserting data into database on signup page. I want to do this validation using javascript.

I tried doing it using compare validator but it did not worked.

Comment: Make an ajaxcall and check in database for duplicate value.

Comment: You can never do this using javascript only, this is client side script. You need to call server side method to fetch data from database and then compare it. Only one thing with javascript is possible i.e. calling the service using javascript/ ajax to do this comparison.

Comment: What have you tried? Saying you tried with comparevalidator does not seems you tried hard. Thad said, I would suggest your to use the out of the box membership providers and the login/register controls. It would be quite easier.

Comment: Can you show some code? Anyway, since this kind of info is usually on the server you need to do your validation using ajax, so by the `remote` method: http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some way to do this.

1. You send all the `username` to the javascript when the page load and validate against the username list.
2. You make an AJAX query to your server to validate the username from the client side.
3. When the user submit the signup form, you validate the username received against your database and send an error if you find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to call a server side method that verify if the username already exist. This can be done very easy with JQuery. Look at the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/